# Minimum elements needed to retrieve data for users from an exposed endpoint in Mule considering the flow logic already exists?

Tags: mule

I am confused as to what are the elements that are considered necessary to retrieve data for users from an exposed Endpoint like (http://localhost/users/).

Is it http:listener-endpoint or http:listener-config or both?

Comment: What mule version are you using? Are you intending to expose an HTTP endpoint at http://localhost/users/

Comment: I am using Anypoint Studio 5.2.1 and yes I am intending to expose an HTTP endpoint at localhost/users.

Comment: I meant is what mule runtime version? If its 3.6 and above, you need both. If lower, only the listener config.. It is easy to follow the documentation and Mule have tutorials too.. If you need to expose multiple endpoints, best to use APIKit which lets you configure REST endpoints from a RAML file.

Comment: @TyroneVillaluna- yes I am using Mule 3.7.1 Runtime so i guess i would need both. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're asking is explained in [Mule docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/http-listener-connector)

You need both - http connector and its configuration. To listen http://localhost/users/ just specify 'users' in http connector path.